# Modal Shapes Circular Plate

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to produce the next figures:
[image]
[image]

I try with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{20}]
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
samples=30,trig format=rad,
domain=1:0, y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({((1-(x^2))^2)*cos(y)},
{((1-(x^2))^2)*sin(y)},x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I do not understand why it does not produce what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal for the mesh only. The blue curve can be done, too, but is more involved.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{20},unit vector ratio=1 1 0.5]
\addplot3[mesh,color=black,%surf,shader=flat,
samples=31,trig format=rad,
domain=0:2, y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({x*cos(y)},
{x*sin(y)},{cos(x*pi)/(1+x*x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working with small modifications  to the code.